# Bivariate models: partial correlation? difference with 2 univariate models?

Tags: correlation, multivariate-analysis, bivariate, partial-correlation

I am interested in estimating the correlation between 2 traits and the effect of a variable (treatment) on each of them. I am using the MCMCglmm package to perform a bivariate linear mixed model, but this question doesn't concern bayesian models in particular.

For those knowing MCMCglmm, the formula is:

```
cbind(trait1,trait2)~trait:treatment-1,random=~us(trait):group, 
                rcov = ~ us(trait):units
```

**Questions:**

1. Can the correlation between dependent variables estimated in this kind of model be called partial correlation? (I haven't seen this term often for those models.) If not, what is the difference?
2. How does the correlation modify the estimate of the treatment effect in comparison with 2 univariate models? 
   Is it statistically wrong to neglect this potential correlation by using 2 separates univariate models to test for the treatment effect?